# Ubuntu Phone on bq: How to show which sim is used while incoming call

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there any possibility to see on which sim the incoming call is coming ?

Comment: thanks was in hollidays and had no time for it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion, I have open request about it. If you are affected by this, you can join:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dialer-app/+bug/1455069

Comment: and it would be great to have different sounds on each sim.

Comment: For me, any initial option would be an important step.
I think that you can contribute your own experience or suggestions to the bug thread

Comment: sry. don't know howto do this.

Comment: After login, at bottom of the page, "Add comment". 
I'm sorry, probably I do not follow more these threads, I'll sell the BQ. Regards

Comment: If you are affected by this too, i.e. you have an Aquaris 4.5 or 5 HD, please take a moment while you are on the Launchpad page of the bug and mark it as affecting you too. You can do so towards the top left hand side of the page. This will increase the bug heat and may work towards getting this fixed faster. Also, if you subscribe to receiving an email, once the bug is closed, you will know when to expect it in the next update and it always counts towards the bug heat.

Answer (score 1):

Solved in OTA-9 (2016/01/27) by SIM tag
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telephony-service/+bug/1460301

Answer (score 0):

That's not doable at the moment, you should open a request about it on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dialer-app/+filebug